# Pivot and replace XDocument's nested element array of chars with a single string

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, data-manipulation

Having XML like this:

```
<ReplyMessage>
  <tran>
    <ser_num>305</ser_num>
    <time>1490987995</time>
    <source_type>0</source_type>
    <source_number>0</source_number>
    <tran_type>126</tran_type>
    <tran_code>50</tran_code>
    <t_diag>
      <bfr>S</bfr>
      <bfr>o</bfr>
      <bfr>c</bfr>
      <bfr>k</bfr>
      <bfr>e</bfr>
      <bfr>t</bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr>r</bfr>
      <bfr>e</bfr>
      <bfr>c</bfr>
      <bfr>v</bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr>o</bfr>
      <bfr>n</bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr>s</bfr>
      <bfr>o</bfr>
      <bfr>c</bfr>
      <bfr>k</bfr>
      <bfr>e</bfr>
      <bfr>t</bfr>
      <bfr>-</bfr>
      <bfr>7</bfr>
      <bfr>4</bfr>
      <bfr>:</bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr>f</bfr>
      <bfr>a</bfr>
      <bfr>i</bfr>
      <bfr>l</bfr>
      <bfr>e</bfr>
      <bfr>d</bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr>-</bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr>3</bfr>
      <bfr>0</bfr>
      <bfr>7</bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
      <bfr></bfr>
    </t_diag>
  </tran>
</ReplyMessage>
```

I wished to replace the array of nested `<bfr>` elements under `<t_diag>` with a simple string element:

```
<ReplyMessage>
  <tran>
    <ser_num>305</ser_num>
    <time>1490987995</time>
    <source_type>0</source_type>
    <source_number>0</source_number>
    <tran_type>126</tran_type>
    <tran_code>50</tran_code>
    <t_diag>
      <bfr>Socket recv on socket-74: failed - 307</bfr>
    </t_diag>
  </tran>
</ReplyMessage>
```

So, piecing together several posts from StackOverflow and MSDN, I arrived at this method, which does the job:

```
private XElement XmlPivotCharArrayToStr(XDocument xmlDoc, string parentName, string arrayName)
{
    XElement parent = xmlDoc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == parentName).FirstOrDefault();
    string st = string.Join("", parent.Elements(arrayName).Select(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value) ? " " : x.Value)).TrimEnd();
    parent.RemoveAll();
    XElement newElement = new XElement(arrayName, st);
    parent.Add(newElement);
    return newElement;
}
```

Called like this:

```
    //// Some initial cleanup to convert character array into string
    XmlPivotCharArrayToStr(xmlDoc, parentName: "t_diag", arrayName: "bfr");
```

Now, this works, in my specific context, but I have the feeling that several improvements could be made:

1. Is there a way I could have specified an explicit path to parentName instead of using .Descendants() method?
2. Is there a better way to swap out the array and replace it with the string? - parent.RemoveAll() may be overkill.
3. Is there a way to detect the end of the array to avoid using TrimEnd()

Thanks in advance for any tips - I'm hoping others find (the improved version) this useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can select target node with xpath. For that, use extension methods (add `using System.Xml.XPath`). Then just:

   ```
   XElement parent = xmlDoc.XPathSelectElement(path);
   ```

Where `path` in your case is `"/ReplyMessage/tran/t_diag"`.

2. I think `RemoveAll` is fine, but if you have doubts - you can remove `t_diag` itself, like this:

   ```
   XElement newElement = new XElement(arrayName, st);
   var grandParent = parent.Parent;
   parent.Remove();
   grandParent.Add(new XElement(parent.Name, newElement));
   ```
3. `TrimEnd` is fine. To detect if all elements at the end are empty you need to watch all of them anyway - so you cannot do much better.

Comment: Thanks, that's great advice